# Mouse battery status not working

Tags: mouse

I do not think mate-power-statistics or upower is working.

Mouse is a Logitech M325.

I have tried 3 different batteries and they all show 55%.

One AA battery and two NiMh batteries.

What is wrong?

Comment: Same here. I have Logitech wireless keyboard + mouse combo, K545 + M510. Battery indicator for the keyboard is quite accurate. But the mouse one is always on 55%. Looks like there's something wrong with the battery indicator, or driver, or kernel? I'm using Arch.

Comment: Having the same issue and looking for a solution , Logitech M510 mouse on Linux Mint.